# Batch File to return file name and multiple strings

Tags: batch-file

I have used simple batch files in the past for finding strings in a single txt file and merging multiple txt files, but this one is a bit more complex and I am not sure where to start.

Here is a break down of what I am trying to do:

Have one folder with 300+ txt files

Each txt file has at least one, but maybe hundreds of occurrences of the string "documentID:", with a 6 charters following it.

Want a txt file or a csv with the file name of the txt file, and for every time the string "documentID:" is found in the txt file - the 6 following characters

Example:

jsmith.txt:

```
<type>not needed</type>
<version>1.0</version>
not needed,not needed, not needed, documentID:NEED01, not needed
not needed,not needed, not needed, documentID:NEED02, not needed
```

jdoe.txt

```
<type>not needed</type>
<version>1.0</version>
not needed,not needed, not needed, documentID:NEED03, not needed
```

Desired output:

new.txt

```
jsmith, NEED01, NEED02
jdoe, NEED03
```

Comment: Is this some kind of hybrid XML file?  Is each document id on its own line? Is it always in the 4th comma delimited field?

Comment: yes these are xml files (but for the need of output ill be making them txt files)  - the needed content is not always in the fourth field, and sometimes there are many more or a lot less of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%A in (*.txt) do (
    set "out="
    for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%B in (`findstr /rc:"documentID:[^^,]*" "%%A"`) do (
        set "str=%%B"
        set "val=!str:*documentID:=!"
        set "tail=!val:*,=!"
        call set "res=%%val:,!tail!=%%"
        set "out=!out!, !res!"
    )
    echo %%~nA!out!
)

endlocal


Rem  For mentioned jsmith.txt and jdoe.txt will output
Rem
Rem  jdoe, NEED03
Rem  jsmith, NEED01, NEED02
```

The first `for` loop iterates through all `*.txt` files in the current dir.

The second `for` loop iterates through the output of the `findstr` command.

The `findstr` command looks for strings with `documentID:*,` pattern. The `documentID` word is case sensitive. The `,` symbol should follow the pattern.

The `set "val=!str:*documentID:=!"` command erases the beginning of the found string and the `documentID:` word.

The `set "tail=!val:*,=!"` command receives all symbols after the `documentID:*,` pattern.

The `call set "res=%%val:,!tail!=%%"` command extracts the value right after the `documentID:` word.

Comment: Nice solution +1, why not use `!val:~0,6!` instead of tail and res?

Comment: Premature optimization :) For case when ID's length can be variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input!   I will try this out next week Tuesday (heading out for holiday break) and get back to you with how it worked out....but your explanation makes a lot of sense.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

The following script does what you want, supposing every needed string portion is in its own line:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_LOCATION=%~dp0."    & rem // (path to the directory containing the input files)
set "_PATTERN=*.txt"      & rem // (pattern the input files need to match)
set "_PREFIX=documentID:" & rem // (string that precedes the needed string portion)
set "_SEPAR=, "           & rem // (field separator for both input and output files)

rem // Loop through all matching input files:
for %%F in ("%_LOCATION%\%_PATTERN%") do (
    rem // Initialise collection variable with the name of the currently iterated file:
    set "COLLECT=%%~nxF"
    rem // Search current file for predefined prefix and loop over all applicable lines:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('findstr /C:"%_PREFIX%" "%%~F"') do (
        rem // Store currently processed line:
        set "ITEM=" & set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose any exclamation marks `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Split off the prefix and everything in front of it, then split off the
        rem    next separator (regard first character only) and everything behind: */
        for /F "delims=%_SEPAR:~,1% eol=%_SEPAR:~,1%" %%K in ("!LINE:*%_PREFIX%=!") do (
            endlocal
            set "ITEM=%%K"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        rem /* Append extracted string portion to collection variable and transport the
        rem    result over the `endlocal` barrier using the `for /F` command: */
        for /F "delims= eol=:" %%K in ("!COLLECT!%_SEPAR%!ITEM!") do (
            endlocal
            set "COLLECT=%%K"
        )
    )
    rem // Return the collected line for the currently iterated file:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!COLLECT!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

To store the result in a text file, use redirection; for example, the script is saved as `merge-files.bat` and the resulting text file should be `D:\result\new.csv`, call the script like this:

```bat
merge-files.bat > "D:\result\new.csv"
```